How to estimate the expression about triangle and orthocenter.

In the acute triangle $\triangle ABC $, $ H $ is the orthocenter. The rays $ AH, BH, CH $ intersect the circumcircle of $ \triangle ABC $ at points $A', B', C' $ respectively. Determine:
$
\hspace{10em} \frac{(6)}{(7)} \leq \frac{AH}{AA'} + \frac{BH}{BB'} + \frac{CH}{CC'} < \frac{(8)}{\underline{(9)}}
$

Here is my solution:
$\hspace{2em}$Let $S = \frac{AH}{AA'} + \frac{BH}{BB'} + \frac{CH}{CC'}$ and $R$ be the radius of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. We observe that
$
\hspace{17em}AH=2R \cos A,
$
$
\hspace{17em}BH=2R \cos B,
$
$
\hspace{17em}CH=2R \cos C.
$\
Also, by the law of sine, we obtain
$
\hspace{7em}AA'=2R \cos \angle ABA'=2R \cos(B+90^\circ-c) = 2R \cos(C-B).
$
This can also be applied to $BB'$ and $CC'$.Therefore 
$
\hspace{2em}\frac{AH}{AA'} + \frac{BH}{BB'} + \frac{CH}{CC'}=\sum \frac{\cos A}{\cos(C-B)} = -\sum \frac{\cos(B+C)}{\cos(C-B)} 
$
$
\hspace{2em}= \sum \frac{\cos B \cos c - \sin B \sin C}{\cos B \cos c + \sin B \sin C} = \sum \frac{1-\cot B \cot C}{1+\cot B \cot C} = -3+2(\frac {1}{1+\cot B \cot C}+\frac {1}{1+\cot C \cot A}+\frac {1}{1+\cot A \cot B})
$
Let $x=\cot B \cot C,y=\cot C \cot A,z=\cot A \cot B$.
Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}, x>0$, then $f(x)$ is a convex function, thus by Jensen inequality,
$
\hspace{7em}f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \geq 3f(\frac{x+y+z}{3}) = 3f(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{9}{4},
$
thus $S \geq -3+2\cdot \frac{9}{4} = \frac{3}{2}$, equality holds when $A=B=C$, that is when $\triangle ABC $ is an equilateral triangle. But I couldn't figure out the maximum.
$\hspace{2em}$Also, I think my solution to the minimum is pretty indirect. Is there a better way?

Where is this problem taken from?

From my country’s tst

What is $\underline{(9)}$? More generally, what are you denoting with $(n)$?

Those number the index of the bubble sheet. That is, I need to fill in the number 6 blank with 3, the number 7 blank with 2, the number 8blank

We have to maximize $S$, given by:
$$
{S+3\over2}={1\over1+bc}+{1\over1+ca}+{1\over1+ab},
$$
where I set: $a=\cot A$, $b=\cot B$ and $c=\cot C$.
But $C=\pi-A-B$, that is:
$$
c={1-ab\over a+b}.
$$
Substituting that into the first equation, the RHS becomes:
$$
f(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{-a^2b+2 a+b}+\frac{a+b}{-a b^2+a+2 b}+\frac{1}{a b+1},
$$
where $a>0$, $b>0$ and $ab<1$ (the last inequality comes from $C<\pi/2$).
To find the extrema, we can solve the system $\partial f/\partial a=0$ and
$\partial f/\partial b=0$, whose only real positive solution is
$a=b=1/\sqrt3$, corresponding to the minimum $S=3/2$.
The maximum must then be attained on the border of the domain. In fact:
$$
f(0,b)=f(a,0)=f(a,1/a)={5\over2}
$$
corresponding to $S=2$. Of course this is not a maximum but rather a supremum, because we get it only for right triangles.

Proceeding along OP's lines.
(1) For the lower bound
By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+y}+ \frac{1}{1+z}
\ge \frac{9}{1 + x + 1 + y + 1 + z} = \frac94.$$
Thus, $S \ge 2 \cdot \frac94 - 3 = \frac32$
with equality if $x = y = z = 1/3$ (i.e. $A = B = C = \pi/3$).
(2) For the upper bound
Since $\frac{1}{1 + u} - (1 - u/2) = - \frac{u(1-u)}{2(1+u)} < 0$ for all $u \in (0, 1)$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+y}+ \frac{1}{1+z}
< 1 - \frac{x}{2} + 1 - \frac{y}{2} + 1 - \frac{z}{2} = \frac52.$$
Thus, $S < 2 \cdot \frac52 - 3 = 2$.
Also, when $\max(A, B, C) \to \pi/2$, we have $S \to 2$.
